# How do I link to data in a partial that's rendered through Ajax?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm rendering a product catalog using AJAX. Collections have subcategories whose products are rendered as AJAX partials. I tried to link to those pages from other parts of the site through regular links (without remote:true) and obviously, it didn't work since the show action in my subcategories controller was only responding to js.

I tried to solve it by adding format.html to the subcategories controller and creating a show.html.erb file, in addition to the _show.html.erb and show.js.erb. The subcategories/show is exactly the same as collections/show and the AJAX links all work fine. But it's rendering other subcategories partials from the one URL which looks confusing, and it's also repeating a lot of code.

Is there a way I can link to the collection page from other parts of the site and render the correct subcategories partial? What is the best way to handle this kind of situation?

subcategories_controller.rb

```
def show
  @subcategory = Subcategory.friendly.find(params[:id])
  @collection = @subcategory.collection

  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
    format.html
  end
end
```

collections/show.html.erb

```
<% @collection.subcategories.each do |subcategory| %>
    <%= link_to subcategory.name, [collection, subcategory], remote: true %>
<% end %>

<div class="product-grid">
</div>
```

subcategories/show.js.erb

```
document.querySelector(".product-grid").innerHTML = "<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'show', locals: { subcategory: @subcategory } ) %>";
```

subcategories/show.html.erb

```
<!-- same as collections/show.html.erb !-->
```

Comment: The question is a bit confusing - what is "ajax-y" in all the above? It _seems_ you're `render`ing a partial (end of day). _Typically_ if you want the client/js to do the rendering, you'll get some data structure (e.g. `JSON`) and then build the UI (aka "render") via JS as opposed to the above where you're still asking the Rails engine to `render` (end of day) for you.

Comment: @EdSF I forgot to include the `remote: true` when I was writing the question